# How do I retrieve the view count of a video on YouTube using the YouTube API 3 and Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to retrieve view counts for a specific video.  I have set up my application, created an OATH2 connection, etc.

The URL I am using is: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video-id}&key={API-key}%20&fields=items(statistics)&part=statistics

Directly going to this URL correctly responds with a JSON formatted response, with all the information I need. I've tried this in multiple browsers, and made sure I was signed out of my account while using the URL. It still responds correctly.

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "21997",
    "likeCount": "1",
    "dislikeCount": "2",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "2"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

However, when I try to Parse this information, the results are not as expected:

```
<script>

    $.getJSON("{https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video-id}&key={API-key}%20&fields=items(statistics)&part=statistics", function(data) {

        $("#results").append('<p>' + data.items.statistics.viewCount + '</p>');

    });

</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

1. "data.items.statistics.viewCount"(which is the information I want to retrieve), returns the response "undefined"

   ```
   $("#results").append('<p>' + data.items.statistics.viewCount + '</p>');
   ```
2. Just to test it out, I treid using "data" as the variable above, and using "data.items", and I get the response "[object Object]"

   ```
   $("#results").append('<p>' + data.items + '</p>');
   ```
3. If I change "data" to "data.items.statistics", I get the response "undefined"

   ```
   $("#results").append('<p>' + data.items.statistics + '</p>');
   ```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, and how to correct this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the items is not an object property is an array.
Try to 
    `$("#results").append('<p>' + data.items[0].statistics.viewCount + '</p>');`

I hope that solves your problem.